# How to Solve 'LeadForm' object has no attribute 'save' error in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to submit data through a form, but it's showing me this error `'LeadForm' object has no attribute 'save'`, Please let me know how I can solve this issue. I am stuck in this for the last 4 hours but still did not find the solution.

I have another page on my website where a product page is opened, and there is a form, When the user submit the form then his/her information should be store in my database, But I am stuck in this, I submitted lots of forms but I am still unable to resolve this error.

Here is my `forms.py` file...

```
class LeadForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        exclude = ['lead_for','property_type','status','source','message','user']
        fields = ['customer_name', 'customer_email', 'customer_phone']
```

here is my `views.py` file code...

```
def leads(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LeadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = LeadForm()
    return HttpResponse('Fail')
```

here is my `urls.py` file...

```
 path('query/sendquery', views.leads, name='leads'),
```

here is my `leads.html` file...

```
<form action="{% url 'panel:leads' %}" id="queryform" method="POST">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <div class="chat-group mt-1">
                                                <input class="chat-field" type="text" name="name" id="customer_name" placeholder="Your name" required="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="chat-group mt-1">
                                                <input class="chat-field" type="number" name="customer_phone" id="customer_phone" placeholder="Phone" required="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="chat-group mt-1">
                                                <input class="chat-field" type="text" name="email" id="customer_email" placeholder="Email" required="">
                                            </div>
                                        
                                            <div class="chat-button mt-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

here is my `models.py` file..

```
class Leads(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Immediate Purchase'),
        ('2', 'Site Visit'),
        ('3', 'Just Information')
     )
    SOURCE = (
        ('1', 'Facebook'),
        ('2', 'Website'),
        ('3', 'PPC'),
        ('4', 'Reference'),
        ('5', 'Other Source')
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userAssignLead', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    customer_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    customer_phone = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    lead_for = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    source = models.CharField(choices=SOURCE, null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

Comment: `LeadForm` is a `Form`, not a `ModelForm`, so it can not save anything, since it does not corresponds toa  model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not make `LeadForm` an instance of `ModelForm`, hence it does not know anything about a related model and how to save it:

```
# inherit from ModelForm  ↓
class LeadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        exclude = ['lead_for','property_type','status','source','message','user']
        fields = ['customer_name', 'customer_email', 'customer_phone']
```

It also does not make much sense to mention *both* `fields` and `exclude`: if you list the fields, then automatically the other ones are excluded:

```
# inherit from ModelForm  ↓
class LeadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Leads
        fields = ['customer_name', 'customer_email', 'customer_phone']
```

Note that the fields you exclude should be optional at the model, or you should fill in a value in the view. Otherwise you try to save the object without a `user`, `source`, `message`, etc. and likely the database will reject this.

Comment: only `customer_name` and `customer_phone` is required in databse, rest all is blank and null, but when I am submitting the form after filling data, then it's redirecting to `return HttpResponse('Fail')`

Comment: What is the exact error that my data is not submitting in database after submit the form..

Comment: I have updated my `models.py` file also, please check my updated question

Comment: @Amit: please don't redirect to anything like fail. Normlally you *rerender* the template with the form. You can see the errors with `form.errors`.

Comment: I want to send on thank you page, but data is not saving in my database

Comment: @Amit: of course not, since the form *validates* the data, and *rejects* it. If you `print(form.errors)`, then you can see *why*.

Comment: how i can eignore these fields in form `(1048, "Column 'property_type' cannot be null")
`, i want to save `name, email , phone` when i submit the form

Comment: @Amit: this is exactly what I warned about. Since `property_type` is non-nullable (you did not set `null=True`), nor you did set a `default=...` value, it can not be saved without giving it a value...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223246/discussion-between-amit-and-willem-van-onsem).